# custom validation phalcon without library

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm beginner in PHP and phalcon, I want to use custom validation and creating default value.

My controller is:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class OspoController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function createAction()
    {

        $ospo = new Ospos();

        // Store and check for errors
        $success = $ospo->save(
            $this->request->getPost(),
            array('isEmailConfirmed', 'email', 'password', 'salt' ,'phoneNum', 'verifiedPhoneStatus', 'languageId', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'cityId', 'provId', 'countryId', 'postCode')
        );
        $data = array();
        if ($success) {
            $data[] = array(
                'status' => 'success'
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            foreach ($ospo->getMessages() as $message) {
                $msg = $message->getMessage();
                $data[] = array(
                    'message' => $msg
                );

            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }

        $this->view->disable();
    }
```

I want if `isEmailConfirmed` is `null` - I want to create value that `isEmailConfirmed = 0;`

How to change array value of `getPost()`?

(can I do this) Should i change the code with 
`$isEmailConfirmed = $_POST['isEmailConfirmed']`;

and 
`$ospo->save($isEmailConfirmed, $etc, $etc)`?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you sending `isEmailConfirmed` ?  via ajax / form submit?

Comment: it's later via token from user email @Timothy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can just store POST data in a variable. Then just check for null and assign default value if needed before saving.

```
$data = $this->request->getPost();
if (!isset($data['isEmailConfirmed']) {
    $data['isEmailConfirmed'] = 0;
}
```

Another way is to save null value, but in that case you should set up DEFAULT for that column in your database table.